# Accessing Const Variable in a Function - React

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to access/use variables in a function somewhere other than that function itself?

For example:

```
function Function1() {
     const [hello, setHello] = useState('hello'); 

     return(
           ['returns something other than const hello']
     )
}

function Function2() {
     var hello2 = ['uses const hello']
}
```

This is just a simple example, but is there a way? If there isn't, what is a method that could allow me to use a variable from within a function or something else, elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to directly access the variable itself--it doesn't exist outside the function. But there are countless ways to share data between unrelated functions.

### In React Components:

In React when you encounter a situation in which multiple components need access to the same state it's usually a sign that you should [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

So in your example (assuming these are React components) you could do something like this:

```
// component takes a 'value' prop without caring where it comes from
function ChildA ({ value }) {
  return (
    <div>Child A says {value}</div>
  )
}

// same as above
function ChildB ({ value }) {
  return (
    <div>Child B also says {value}</div>
  )
}

// controls the state and passes it down as a prop
function Parent () {
  const [hello, setHello] = useState('hello');
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildA value={hello} />
      <ChildB value={hello} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

### In javascript more generally

You can follow the same principle, moving shared data up, in javascript generally (non-react):

```js
let hello = 'hello';

function a() {
  console.log(hello);
}

function b() {
  console.log(hello);
}

a(); // logs 'hello'
b(); // logs 'hello'

hello = 'howdy';

a(); // logs 'howdy'
b(); // logs 'howdy'
```

---

### Using a store with imports/exports

A common pattern for this sort of thing is to use a dedicated "store" class as the source of truth.

I've commented out the imports and exports in the snippet below because they don't make sense in a snippet (and more importantly, they don't work in a snippet).

```js
// HelloStore.js

class HelloStore {
  // keep track of the value internally
  _hello = 'hello';

  // setter
  set hello(newValue) {
    this._hello = newValue;
  }

  // getter
  get hello() {
    return this._hello;
  }
}

const store = new HelloStore();
// export default store;


// Foo.js
// import store from './HelloStore';

function foo () {
  console.log(store.hello);
}


// Bar.js
// import store from './HelloStore';

function bar () {
  console.log(store.hello);
}

foo(); // logs 'hello'
bar(); // logs 'hello'

store.hello = 'howdy'

foo(); // logs 'howdy'
bar(); // logs 'howdy'
```

---

### Getting change notifications from the store

It's often desirable for components or other code to be alerted to changes to the store value. You can facilitate this by making the store an [event emitter](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter).

```js
// This is just a dumber implementation of node's
// event emitter because i can't import it here.
// No reason you'd need to roll your own emitter
// in a real project.
class EventEmitter {
  listeners = [];
  addEventListener (handler) {
    this.listeners.push(handler);
  }
  emit (data) {
    this.listeners.forEach(handler => handler(data));
  }
}

// HelloStore.js

class HelloStore extends EventEmitter {
  // keep track of the value internally
  _hello = 'hello';

  // setter
  set hello(newValue) {
    this._hello = newValue;
    this.emit(newValue); // alert the listeners to the update
  }

  // getter
  get hello() {
    return this._hello;
  }
}

const store = new HelloStore();
// export default store;


// Foo.js
// import store from './HelloStore';

function foo(value) {
  console.log(`foo says ${value}`);
}

function bar(value) {
  console.log(`bar says ${value}`);
}

// register listeners to invoke foo
// and bar when the store value changes
store.addEventListener(foo);
store.addEventListener(bar);

// emits event, triggers listeners
store.hello = 'howdy';

// emits event, triggers listeners
store.hello = 'bonjour';
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Just wondering, is it possible to access a const variable in another file? Something like, exporting the const variable hello from function Parent().

Comment: Sure. I'll update my answer with a simple example.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see!! Thank you so much :3333

Comment: Just another question, is it possible to transfer a const variable if it is being updated in HelloStore()? For example, the original value of hello is 'hello', but let's say, when a button is clicked, the value of hello becomes 'good bye.' Is there a way to make foo() print out 'good bye' instead of 'hello?'

Comment: The examples in my answer already do that.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much :33333 I greatly appreciate this! It was really informative :333333333